# Laravel multiple orderBy on same column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause, eager-loading

First I'm including some things I tried, as I think it's quite self explanatory to what I'm trying to do.

```
$event->load(['dates' => function($q) {

 $q->where( DB::raw('DATE(start_time)'), '>=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
   ->orderBy('start_time', 'asc')

   ->where( DB::raw('DATE(start_time)'), '<', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
   ->orderBy('start_time', 'desc');

}]);
```

or

```
$event->load(['dates' => function($q) {

 $q->where( DB::raw('DATE(start_time)'), '>=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
   ->orderBy('start_time', 'asc')

   ->orWhere(function($query) {

     $query->where( DB::raw('DATE(start_time)'), '<', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
           ->orderBy('start_time', 'desc');
     });

}]);
```

### What I'm trying to do

I have an EVENTS table with an `hasMany` relation to DATES. I'm trying to eager load the related dates **first** in **ascending** order for the upcoming dates and then in **descending** order for the dates that have already passed.

With anything I try, the `orderBy` is always ordering **all** the results and not the `where` query. How to approach this problem?

---

Many thanks - correct answer will of course be voted up and selected as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, actually found two suitable solutions to my problem. Thanks to **@Bernie** for giving me a push in the right direction - that I can't have two different orders in the same query and looking for something like **union / merge**.

---

### With Multiple Queries

First line is **Eager Loading** just the **upcoming dates** in the `$event`.

Second you get the **past dates** and third you merge them together.

Only bad thing - you have to execute multiple (two) queries and this isn't optimal.

```
    $event->load(['dates' => function($q) {
        $q->where( DB::raw('DATE(start_time)'), '>=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') )
          ->orderBy('start_time');
    }]);

    $past = $event->dates()
                  ->where( DB::raw('DATE(start_time)'), '<', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') )
                  ->orderBy('start_time', 'desc')                 
                  ->get();

    $event->dates = $event->dates->merge($past);
```

---

### Collection Methods

First you **Eager Load** all the dates belonging to the event.

Second you `filter` all the **past dates** and `reverse` them - all this by using **Collection Methods**.

Then you `count` the past dates, `splice` them from the original **Collection** and merge the new reversed **Collection** back.

```
    $event->load(['dates' => function($q) {
        $q->orderBy('start_time');
    }]);

    $filtered = $event->dates->filter(function ($item) {
        return $item->raw_date < Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    })->reverse();

    $event->dates->splice(0, $filtered->count());
    $event->dates = $event->dates->merge($filtered);
```

---

### Conclusion

First method uses two **Queries** which is not optimal - second method uses quite a lot of **Collection Methods**.

If someone could indicate which one  would be more efficient, would be very helpful!

Comment: Why not use a `UNION` to get all the dates in a single DB query? By the way, if your dates are stored as one of the date types in the DB, you don't need to use `->format('Y-m-d')` or DB:raw. The Cardon instance can be used directly if you use a regular `::where`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two different orders on the same query. What you can have however, is two subqueries, with each their own order, `union`ed together like you want them to be.